# Format SSD and restore TM backup

Tags: macos, disk-format, recovery-hd

My SSD stopped mounting by itself on boot. So I booted into Single User mode, ran `/sbin/mount/ -uw /` and `exit` and it got mounted and I could boot from the SSD. However, after booting all I see is the Guest user and not the admin user.

However, I have a TM backup and would like to simple erase the entire disk and restore. The issue is I can't erase the disk in Recovery Mode using Disk Utility as it does not get mounted automatically.

What would be the best approach?

Comment: How can you boot in Single User Mode? Isn't your SSD the bootdisk?

Comment: @CousinCocaine it's quite common to have a system that boots enough to get to the prompt in single user mode yet still has severe issues on the OS and/or the user level...

Comment: I did not know. But the first line made it confusing: "My SSD stopped mounting by itself on boot". The Single User Mode is on the same partition as the System and not on the Recovery partition, right?

Answer (score 1):

Hold down the <kbd>Command</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd> keys at startup to start the computer from the Recovery system. The Recovery menu that appears includes the option to restore from a Time Machine backup.

- First: delete your SSD drive using Disk Utility. (Mac OS Extended (Journaled))
- Second: Choose for Backup from TimeMachine.

And now we wait...

*It would be wise to connect your machine using an network cable instead of WiFi.*